# Derive Torque $\tau = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}$ from $\tau= I\alpha$

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

```
I have started learning about rotational mechanics about a month back. I am trying to derive everything from the fundamentals.<br>
```

First off, I derive the relation for the moment of inertia using the Kinetic energy argument. ($I= \int_0^m r^2 dm$) 
From here by analogy to linear dynamics, I state Angular momentum $\mathbf{L}= I  \boldsymbol{\omega}$
Again, as an analogy to Newton's 3rd Law, I say
Moment of Force (Torque) = rate of change of angular momentum= $I  \boldsymbol{\alpha} $

Now, I am having trouble proving that
$$I \boldsymbol{\alpha} = \mathbf{r} \times  \mathbf{F}$$ ($I, \boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are w.r.t the same axis).
I am able to prove it easily for a point mass system, where the force is applied on the mass directly,  but unable to prove it for a general Rigid body.
$I$=moment of inertia

$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$= Angular acceleration vector

$ \boldsymbol{\omega}$=Angular velocity vector

$\mathbf{r}$ = Position vector

$\mathbf{F}$ = Force vector

 
 
EDIT 
I tried something new but it seems contradictory...
torque= I $\alpha$
= $\alpha \int_0^m r^2 dm $
=$\alpha ( \int_0^m r \times r dm) $ 
now using integration by parts,
torque=$\alpha (r \int_0^m r dm  - \int_0^m ((dr/dm) \int_0^m r dm)dm $ 
By using the relation ,
F= $ \alpha \int_0^m r dm $ 
torque=$ \alpha (r (F / \alpha )  - (F/ \alpha ) (\int_0^r dr)$
=$ \alpha (r (F / \alpha ) - r (F / \alpha )) =0 $

this is certainly not true as torque may not always be 0.
What am I doing wrong here? Also can someone answer my original question with a similar approach?

Answer (score 5):

It isn't always true that $\vec{\boldsymbol{\tau}}=I\vec{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}$. The general form of torque is
$$\vec{\boldsymbol{\tau}}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\vec{\boldsymbol{L}}$$
From definition of angular momentum
$$\vec{\boldsymbol{L}}=\vec{\boldsymbol{r}}\times \vec{\boldsymbol{p}}$$
gives
\begin{align*}
\vec{\boldsymbol{\tau}}&=\dfrac{d}{dt}(\vec{\boldsymbol{r}}\times \vec{\boldsymbol{p}})\\
\vec{\boldsymbol{\tau}}&=\vec{\boldsymbol{r}}\times \dfrac{d\vec{\boldsymbol{p}}}{dt}\\
\end{align*}
and from Newton's second law of motion
$$\vec{\boldsymbol{F}}=\dfrac{d}{dt}\vec{\boldsymbol{p}}$$
then
$$\vec{\boldsymbol{\tau}}=\vec{\boldsymbol{r}}\times\vec{\boldsymbol{F}}\;\blacksquare$$

Comment: well this method raises a similar question of why
 L=r $\times$p  (i started with the definition L=I $\omega$), Still thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Examine any intro to math physics textbook and you'll find the answer readily. Anyway, the angular momentum is defined as the cross product $L = r \times p$ because $L$ will always be perpendicular to the plane containing $r$ and $p$. Thus, the equation $L = I\omega$ is more subtle than you probably know: the inertia $I$ is actually a rank 2 tensor, also called a matrix, so only in very simple cases does $L$ point in the same direction as $\omega$ (i.e. when I is a diagonal matrix). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor

Comment: Nice explanation here http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node64.html

Comment: @saitama because $L=I\omega$ isn't the definition of angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

### Context

If we were being more explicit, we define torque about some origin $\mathrm{O}$ around this origin we can rewrite an inertia element of some mass element some where as:

$$ \Delta I_{i} = |\vec{r_i}|^2 \Delta m_i$$

Where,

$$ \Delta I_i  \text{ is the inertia of the mass element}$$

$$ \Delta{\vec{r_i}} \text{ is the magnitude of position vector from the defined origin O}$$

$$ \Delta{  m_i}  \text{ is the mass element we are considering}$$

Though we cant directly apply the definition of inertia to the whole system, we can indeed apply the definition of it for a point mass on to a small mass element. We can think of shrinking the mass element such that the whole mass is concentrated in a small enough region that we could approximate it.

Better yet, a more intelligent way would be to write this expression using density. Assume we have an object with varying density $\rho$ which depends on $(x,y,z)$ then we can say the mass of that element in some n-volume around region of inspection is given by $ \rho \Delta V_i$ (*). This turns our equation to this form:

$$ \Delta I_i = |r_i|^2 \rho(x,y,z) \Delta V_i$$

Now, given a rigid body, we can think of as partitioning it into small n-volume elements of $ \Delta V_i$ and finding the inertia of each and summing over that. So, what we can do is sum over all the n-volume elements using an n-dimensional integral (**).

$$ I  = \int |r_i|^2 \rho(x,y,z) \Delta V_i$$

### The problem in your post:

In the second method, you had a step where you had done the following:

$$ |r_i|^2 = \vec{r_i} \cdot \vec{r_i}$$

And you had written as:

$$ I = \int \vec{r} \cdot \left[ \vec{r_i} \rho(x,y,z) \Delta V_i  \right]$$

And integrated the above quantity by parts, however, when you do this you are integrating a vector field ($ \int \vec{r} \Delta V_i$)over a volume. This operation does not make any sense by the mathematics that I know of / can find by googling. The [closest thing I found was this quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-integrate-a-vector-field-on-a-volume).

---

**References:**

For a good explanation of how to derive this in detail go see Kleppner and Kolenkow around page-245

**Note:** n-volume is the sort of generalization of volume

Answer (score 0):

**CLUE:**

Radial force on a point:m.$\omega^2$r

Tangential force on it:mr$\alpha$  (Torque due to it :m.$r^2.\alpha$)

Sum over all particles for torque.

$\tau^{net}=\sum[...]=I.\alpha$

Think about whether or not radial force provides any torque or not.

Comment: this method (tang force=  mr $\alpha$ ), looks obvious for a point mass m in circular motion of radius r, where force is applied on the point mass tangentially, but how is this relation valid for a continuous mass( rigid body)?
(i'm assuming that by r, you mean to refer to position vector of point of application of force)

Comment: @saitama If you have understood that part, For a rigid body it is easy, We just have to sum/integrate it for every possible point on the rigid body.

Comment: ok, so I have managed to understand why F=mr $\alpha$ for a rigid body, 
But in third line you say summing over all particles......gives torque. How does summing tangential force give torque? even their dimensions are also differenent

Comment: @saitama I've made an edit(I am summing torque not force), does it seem clear now? Tell me if it doesn't.

Comment: ok now i have got it. Thanks. Also you may look into the new approach i tried (the edit in the question), and tell me what is wrong there, although I have got the answer to my main question by your method.